# this.state not displaying array content, Array(1) = [Array(3)]

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, fetch

I am fetching json data from the public folder's Blog.json file, but the state is returning an array within an array and I'm unable to fetch the data I need.

here is my code:

```
export default class BlogPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            resultsLoaded: true,
            blogs: [],
            error: null
        }
    }

        componentDidMount = () => {
            fetch('./Blog.json')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(
                (result) => {

                    let blogArray = Object.values(result);

                    this.setState({
                        resultsLoaded: true,
                        blogs: blogArray
                    })
                    return blogArray
                },
                (error) => {
                    this.setState({
                        isLoaded: true,
                        error
                    });
                }
            )
        }

        render() {
            const {error, resultsLoaded, blogs} = this.state;

            if (error) {
                return (
                    <div>Error: {error.message}</div>
                );
            } else if (!resultsLoaded) {
                return (
                    <div>Loading.....</div>
                );
            } else {

            console.log(this.state);

                let blogResults = blogs.map((e, index) => (
                    <div>
                        <h3>Working!</h3>
                        <p>{e.title}</p>
                    </div>
                ))
                return (
                    <div>{blogResults}</div>
                );
            }
        }
    }
```

My JSON file looks like this:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "title": "Work Ethic",
            "post": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...",
            "image": "",
            "date": ""
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "title": "Impostor Syndrome",
            "post": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...",
            "image": "",
            "date": ""
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "title": "Getting Hired",
            "post": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...",
            "image": "",
            "date": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

This image is what is logged in the console:
[image]

Also, I am getting the following error: "Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.", and {e.title} doesn't display. I'm guessing due to the array error.

Thanks.

Comment: You get the `key` message because you're not setting a key. Regarding the return value--you get what you get; if you need to dig into the results object then just do that.

Comment: It seems blog array contains another array at index 0.Try logging/printing result before setting it into state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your key warning, do like this: `<div key={index}>` in your immediate div tag under `map` method.

For the other problem can you post your JSON file?

Most probably your `Object.values` is doing this problem. In result if you have something like this: {blogs: [{...}, {...}, {...}]} then obviously your Object.values will behave like this. If you want your intended behaviour then you should write something like `let blogsArr = results.blogs`

Comment: You're right, that is how my json file is structured (I've added it to the question). Thanks, I'll try setting a variable.

Comment: Then just replace your code to get intended behaviour by this: `let blogArr = result.data`

Answer (score 0):

In react each item inside a loop should have a key

please refer [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)

so

```
let blogResults = blogs.map((e, index) => (
                    <div key={index}>
                        <h3>Working!</h3>
                        <p>{e.title}</p>
                    </div>))
   return (<div>{blogResults}</div>);
```

regarding the {e.title} not showing value issue, please check the object has that particular key.